# Parse JSON data from file using C#

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse a json file, but it's being kinda hard to do. I'm using Visual Studio 2019.

I need to take some data from the file.

Here's the Json file's data I need to extract:

```
{
    "Id": "92cb6271-005e-48e9-a319-a606b8b6e1ef",
    "DefaultPosition": {
        "PositionId": "35ed169a-1208-4d8a-8faa-d2627d5790ed",
        "EntityDetails": {
            "DateCreated": "2019-09-17T15:25:52.4942161-03:00",
            "DateModified": "2019-09-17T15:45:28.896274-03:00",
            "CreatedBy": {
                "Id": "1abb5047-8580-4be1-909d-41138035e4c9",
                "ItemDisplayText": "Laurete Araujo",
                "ItemType": "Users"
            },
            "ModifiedBy": {
                "Id": "1abb5047-8580-4be1-909d-41138035e4c9",
                "ItemDisplayText": "Laurete Araujo",
                "ItemType": "Users"
            },
            "Owner": {
                "Id": "1abb5047-8580-4be1-909d-41138035e4c9",
                "ItemDisplayText": "Laurete Araujo",
                "ItemType": "Users"
            }
        },
        "NameComponents": {
        "FullName": "ABRAHÃO DOS SANTOS",
        "FamilyName": "SANTOS",
        "FirstName": "ABRAHÃO DOS"
        },
        "MaritalStatus": {
        "Id": "97d7a9dd-a7c4-4076-829c-7ec63b0e3fe7",
        "DisplayTitle": "Marital Status",
        "ItemDisplayText": "Married",
        "ItemType": "LookupListEntries"
        }
}
```

This is the C# code I'm trying to use, but it's giving me issues:

```
public void JsonParser(string file) 
{
    string fullname;
    string gender;
    string nationality;
    string maritalstatus;

    var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file);

    var objects = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.Parse(json); // parse as array 

    foreach (JObject root in objects)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<String, JToken> app in root)
        {
            var appName = app.Key;
            fullname = (String)app.Value["FullName"];

            if (app.Key == "Gender") 
            {
                gender = (String)app.Value["ItemDisplayText"];
                Console.WriteLine(gender);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(fullname);
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code and I try to import the file from where I want to extract the data, this error appears:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Error reading JArray from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an array: StartObject. Path '', line 1, position 1.'

Thank you!

Comment: Your posted `JSON` string is invalid as per https://jsonlint.com/. Please post the correct `JSON` string

Comment: You may find it simpler to just Deserialize the JSON then just access the desired data as common ordinary object properties.  Thirty minutes of proper research here on past questions will give you most of the basics for such a task.

Comment: @RahulSharma, I'm sorry, I just had cut a piece of the code. The JSON file has a valid JSON. I'm sorry

Comment: Thank you, @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp!

Comment: @Shoy If you cannot post the entire `JSON` string, then paste a block of the string that is valid.

Comment: from what i see the json is not an array. please post the json and/or parse as an object.

Comment: Okay, @RahulSharma! I'll edit the question.

Comment: @Shoy Still not valid `JSON` as per https://jsonlint.com/. Please verify on this to check if you `JSON` is valid.

Comment: @RahulSharma, I still not edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json has an issue its not an array and you are trying to parse it as an jarray,

this is how your json should look like

```
[
    {
      "Id": "92cb6271-005e-48e9-a319-a606b8b6e1ef",
      "DefaultPosition": {
        "PositionId": "35ed169a-1208-4d8a-8faa-d2627d5790ed",
        "EntityDetails": {
          "DateCreated": "2019-09-17T15:25:52.4942161-03:00",
          "DateModified": "2019-09-17T15:45:28.896274-03:00",
          "CreatedBy": {
            "Id": "1abb5047-8580-4be1-909d-41138035e4c9",
            "ItemDisplayText": "Laurete Araujo",
            "ItemType": "Users"
          },
          "ModifiedBy": {
            "Id": "1abb5047-8580-4be1-909d-41138035e4c9",
            "ItemDisplayText": "Laurete Araujo",
            "ItemType": "Users"
          },
          "Owner": {
            "Id": "1abb5047-8580-4be1-909d-41138035e4c9",
            "ItemDisplayText": "Laurete Araujo",
            "ItemType": "Users"
          }
        },
        "NameComponents": {
          "FullName": "ABRAHÃO DOS SANTOS",
          "FamilyName": "SANTOS",
          "FirstName": "ABRAHÃO DOS"
        },
        "MaritalStatus": {
          "Id": "97d7a9dd-a7c4-4076-829c-7ec63b0e3fe7",
          "DisplayTitle": "Marital Status",
          "ItemDisplayText": "Married",
          "ItemType": "LookupListEntries"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

or if you want to get the exact values without treating it as array then you can use this

```
public static void JsonParser(string file)
{
    string fullname;
    string gender;
    string nationality;
    string maritalstatus;

    var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file);

    var objects = JObject.Parse(json);

    fullname = (string)objects["DefaultPosition"]["NameComponents"]["FullName"];
    Console.WriteLine(fullname);
    Console.WriteLine("\n");
}
```

but the ideal approach should be creating a model that has the same structure and deserializing to that particular object.

Comment: Yes, it's not an array, but I cannot edit the json file, it's not what I want to do, I want to modify the C# code to read the file.

Comment: @Shoy you can check the edit for the updated answer

Comment: Hey, Kannangokul, I need extract the date of an array inside this object, what should I do?

Comment: And thank you, it worket for all objects :)

Answer (score 1):

Since the file has { } as the root, that means you cannot use JArray because it isn't an array.  It is a single object.  Instead, you should do this:

```
        var root = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<String, JToken> app in root)
        {
            var appName = app.Key;
            fullname = (String)app.Value["FullName"];

            if (app.Key == "Gender")
            {
                gender = (String)app.Value["ItemDisplayText"];
                Console.WriteLine(gender);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(fullname);
            Console.WriteLine("\n");

        }
```

***Edit - Better answer***

The better answer here is, if this isn't dynamic, declare your c# classes that it will deserialize into and then you can run all this like so:

```
public class CreatedBy
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ItemDisplayText { get; set; }
    public string ItemType { get; set; }
}

public class ModifiedBy
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ItemDisplayText { get; set; }
    public string ItemType { get; set; }
}

public class Owner
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ItemDisplayText { get; set; }
    public string ItemType { get; set; }
}

public class EntityDetails
{
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
    public CreatedBy CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public ModifiedBy ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public Owner Owner { get; set; }
}

public class NameComponents
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

public class MaritalStatus
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string DisplayTitle { get; set; }
    public string ItemDisplayText { get; set; }
    public string ItemType { get; set; }
}

public class DefaultPosition
{
    public string PositionId { get; set; }
    public EntityDetails EntityDetails { get; set; }
    public NameComponents NameComponents { get; set; }
    public MaritalStatus MaritalStatus { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public DefaultPosition DefaultPosition { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
  var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

  var fullname = root.DefaultPosition.NameComponents.FullName;
```

Comment: Thank you, Daniel!
But now this error is showing up:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue.'

Do you know how can I fix it? Thank you!

Comment: @Shoy I updated the answer to something that would be even better than trying to parse directly - but it only works if it isn't dynamic.